# MS Access Integrate with Salesforce Rssbuss ODBC connector

Tags: community

I am using Rssbuss as an ODBC connector to Salesforce and MS Access (temporary solution).  The link between MS Access and Salesforce is a success.

I would like to write an insert statement in Access and create Accounts and Opportunities in my Access DB into SFDC Accounts object and Opportunities object.  This state should establishes the relationship between Accounts and Opportunities.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to INSERT rows from an Access database into Salesforce using the RSSBus ODBC driver, you can write INSERT INTO SELECT statements using linked tables.  First, you'll need to set up linked tables in Access to the Account and Opportunity tables.  Then you can create queries using the linked tables.  For example:

INSERT INTO Salesforce_Account (Name, Fax, ...) SELECT (Name, Fax, ...) FROM YourAccessTable

Where Salesforce_Account is the linked table.  You would need to use separate INSERT queries for the two tables.  You can find Microsoft's reference for this here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx